# Countdown Counter Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am tryin to create a simple counter that counts backwards from 3 to 0 or 5 to 0 or whatever.

It's a timer for a questions so each number needs to be visible to the user.

I tried:

```
for (i=3;i>=0;i--){

   $(".timerInner").delay(500).text( i );

}
```

But had no luck.

Comment: First, the loop is very fast, so all these three statements in the loop body are basically executed at the same time. Second, `text` is not an animation function, so calling `delay` first has no effect. I think there a million countdown scripts for jQuery you can use.

Comment: Please choose a best answer @Splatty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var i =5;

var timer = setInterval( calltimer, 500);

function calltimer(){
    $(".timerInner").append( i );

    if(i == 0){
       clearInterval(timer);
    }
    i--;

}
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using this code, but the .append(i) I swithced with .text(i) append did not seem to show results..

Answer (score 3):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)/[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) instead:

```
var i = 5;

var t = setInterval(function() {
    i === 0 && clearInterval(t);

    $(".timerInner").text(i);
    i--;
}, 1000);​
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use JavaScript method `setTimeout`:

```
function countdown(remainingTime) {
    $('.timerInner').text(remainingTime);
    if (remainingTime > 0)
        setTimeout(function() { countdown(remainingTime - 100); }, 100);
}

​countdown(1000);​
```

Fiddle example to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/MSa8h/1/

Answer (score 0):

uou need to create a loop bassed on setTimeout function, here's a sketch

```
var i = 3;

var calc = function(){
    i--;
    if(i==0){
      //start new iteration
      timeout();
    }else{
      //end loop
      return;
    }

};

var timeout = function(){
    setTimeout(calc,1000);
};
```

Comment: You can also omit the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i =5;

var timer = setInterval( calltimer, 500);

function calltimer(){
   $(".timerInner").text( i );

 if(i == 0){
    clearInterval(timer);
 }
 i--;

}
```

Thanks for the help