# Increment integer by 1; every 1 second

Tags: javascript, time, raphael

My aim is to create identify a piece of code that increments a number by 1, every 1 second:

We shall call our base number indexVariable, I then want to: indexVariable = indexVariable + 1 every 1 second; until my indexVariable has reached 360 -  then I wish it to reset to 1 and carry out the loop again.

How would this be possible in Javascript? - if it makes a difference I am using the Raphael framework.

I have carried out research of JavaScript timing events and the Raphael delay function - but these do not seem to be the answer - can anyone assist?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546389/countdown-counter-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: What are you doing with Raphael? For the timing you can use either setTimeout of setInterval

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` for that reason.

```
var i = 1;

var interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);

function increment(){
    i = i % 360 + 1;
}
```

edit: the code for your your followup-question:

```
var interval = setInterval( rotate, 1000);

function rotate(){
      percentArrow.rotate(1,150,150);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure, how your rotate works, but you may have to store the degrees in a var and increment those var too like in the example above.

Comment: Can I ask a further question: every 1 second - I wish to carry out the following code every second:{percentArrow.rotate(1,150,150);}. How could I implement this using the above code?

Comment: @JHarley1 you do it the same way. You create a `function(){...rotate...}` and call it via `setInterval( function ,time in ms)`.

Comment: @JHarley1 see my edited post. Note, you can clear the interval anytime calling `clearInterval(interval)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var indexVariable = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    indexVariable = ++indexVariable % 360 + 1; // SET { 1-360 }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: off by one error;) first do module and then increment would be the right way. But nice and compact indeed. I prefer not to write the function directly in the `setInterval()` though.

Comment: What is with the 360? i added it and my value went from 0 to 32 to 62

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var indexVariable = 0;
setInterval(
    function () {
        indexVariable = (indexVariable + 1) % 361;
    }, 1000}
```